# Is it possible to write a feature to inject a custom control into a masterpage?

Tags: css, user-controls, features

I have 3 site collections that need a specific css file, and to not have to make changes in multiple places our team has opted for a single masterpage. Instead of creating a second masterpage with a link to this css file, I was wondering if its possible to write a feature to add a user control that contains the css to the masterpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate controls, check [this](http://singchan.com/2010/02/23/branding-sharepoint-2010-collaboration-sites-part-3-in-a-series/) article.